# Optimizing Theta Joins in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have just 2 tables wherein I need to get the records from the first table (big table `10 M` rows) whose `transaction date` is `lesser than or equal to` the `effective date` present in the second table (small table with `1` row), and this result-set will then be consumed by downstream queries.

Table Transact:

```
tran_id | cust_id | tran_amt | tran_dt
1234    | XYZ     | 12.55    | 10/01/2020
5678    | MNP     | 25.99    | 25/02/2020
5561    | XYZ     | 32.45    | 30/04/2020
9812    | STR     | 10.32    | 15/08/2020
```

Table REF:

```
eff_dt |
30/07/2020 |
```

Hence as per logic I should get back the first **3** rows and discard the last record since it is `greater` than the reference date (present in the `REF` table)

Hence, I have used a `non-equi Cartesian Join` between these tables as:

```
select
/*+ MAPJOIN(b) */
a.tran_id,
a.cust_id,
a.tran_amt,
a.tran_dt
from transact a
inner join ref b
on a.tran_dt <= b.eff_dt
```

However, this sql is taking forever to complete due to the `cross Join` with the `transact` table even using `Broadcast` hints.

So is there any smarter way to implement the same logic which will be more efficient than this ? In other words, is it possible to optimize the Theta join in this query ?

Thanks in advance.

So I wrote something like this:

Comment: will it be better if I use `Cross Join` and put the filter in a `where` clause ? Also, are  broadcast hints applicable for theta-joins ?

Comment: 1 row. that surprises me

Comment: what is the time taken if I may ask?

Comment: went pretty quick for me. what r u running on?

Comment: I cannot see any cross join. where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Referring from https://databricks.com/session/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins

Can you try Bucketing on trans_dt (Bucketed on Year/Month only). And write 2 queries to do the same work

1. First query, trans_dt(Year/Month) < eff_dt(Year/Month). So this could help you actively picking up buckets(rather than checking each and every record trans_dt) which is less than 2020/07.
2. second query, trans_dt(Year/Month) = eff_dt(Year/Month) and trans_dt(Day) <= eff_dt(Day)